# Can you map the results of a manual SQL query to objects in Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

In LINQ, you can write a manual SQL query, take the results from it and have LINQ "map" those into the appropriate properties of your Model classes (or at least, I'm pretty sure I read you can do that).

Is it possible to do something like that in Entity Framework?

I have an web app that's using EF, and it's CPU usage is ridiculously high compared to the traffic it has, and profiling it in my machine, all that time is (predictably) spent in the DB functions, and the largest portion of that time (> 85%) is spent by EF "generating" SQL and doing stuff before actually executing a query.

So my reasoning is that I can just go in and hardcode the SQL queries, but still use my populated Model properties in my view.

Is this possible? If so, how would I do it?

Thanks!
Daniel

Comment: You need to profile the sql server and figure out if you are missing some indexes.

Comment: I'm not, i'm only JOINing by primary keys, i'm searching only by indexed columns, and again, 85% of the time is spent on the .Net side, not waiting for SQL Server. Which, also, matches "the view from outside" in the production server, where w3wp has 60% of the CPU and SQL has 25%

Comment: Your doing it wrong.  These results are not typical.  Post some code?

Comment: I'm not doing it wrong, my code is fairly typical. What I found out is that apparently I have "too many" calls to .Include (Which you need anyway to get to related data), and that KILLS EF completely. And it's not the JOINs in the DB, SQL responds REALLY fast even with all the JOINs, so either all the Includes are killing EF when generating the query, or when processing the result. Either way, it's ridiculous.

Comment: @Daniel, I think Jason provided the answer. You should set this question as answered. I provided a solution that is also good for EF 4.1+

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So what you want to do is hydrate an object from an `IDataReader`? It's pretty easy to write code to do this (hint: reflection! or you can get fancy and use a member initialization expression) or you can Google for myriad existing implementations on the Internet.

You can do this within EF using [`ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487208.aspx) or [`ObjectContext.Translate<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.translate.aspx) if you already have a `DbDataReader`.

Comment: But esentially LINQ has a feature where this is done automatically, you don't need to use reflection, you just feed it the results (I can't remember if it's an IDataReader specifically, but something close to that), and it'll give you back the IList<YourModel>. The question is whether EF has such a feature.

Comment: Oh, then I think what you want is `ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<T>`, no? Sorry, I initially thought you were subverting EF. (Also, you meant LINQ-to-SQL, not LINQ.)

Comment: It sounds like that is exactly what I need. Is that an EF4 only thing? I'm using the oldest version of EF in the planet (although i'm considering upgrading)

Comment: Yes, that's new to EF4. Upgrade now.

Answer (score 3):

1  **`ObjectContext.SqlQuery` in EF 4.0**

As said @Jason, you can :

```
IEnumerable<MiniClient> results = 
   myContext.SqlQuery<MiniClient>("select name,company from client");
```

Reference : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487208.aspx

2. **`DbContext.Database.SqlQuery`, in EF 4.1+**

In Entity Framework 4.1+, `DbContext` is preferable to use to `ObjectContext`, so you'd better use :

```
DbContext myContext= new DbContext();
IEnumerable<MiniClient> results =
  myContext.SqlQuery<MiniClient>("select name,company from client");
```

Reference : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592907(v=vs.113).aspx

3. **`dynamic` and anonymous class**

Too lazy to create a projection class like MiniClient ?

So you should use anonymous type and dynamic keyword :

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> results =
  myContext.Clients.Select( c => new {Name = c.Name, Firstname = c.Firstname});
```

Note : In all the samples `MiniClient` is not an entity of the `DbContext`.
(=not a `DbSet<T>` property)